# wijmogrid: Header with no content (empty or space)

Tags: wijmo

I wanna create a wijmogrid with a column which header is free.
Tried *blank*, *empty* and *& nbsp;*, but nothing works.

Any ideas? Thanx in advanced.

Comment: Can you update the question with your configuration options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display null value or blank in column headers of WijGrid, you need to set the ‘headerText’ property of each individual column to an empty string.

Here is the code snippet:

```
columns: [
                           { headerText: "" },
                           { headerText: "" },
                           { headerText: "" },
                           { headerText: "" },
                ],
```

For complete implementation, please refer to the following link for sample application:

http://supportftp.componentone.com/WijGrid_BlankColumnHeaders.html

Regards